# xclip does not change the clipboard content

Tags: xclip

I'm trying to give the following command:

```
echo "hi" | xclip -selection c
```

This doesn't work?  It has worked in the past, but never consistently.  I also tried

```
echo "hi" | xclip -selection primary

echo "hi" | xclip -selection clipboard
```

etc....

xclip is installed (I'm pretty familiar with Linux :-) ) and there is no output, it just moves onto the next line and my clipboard contents do not change.

Here is my linux version:

```
[1450] cgeorge@uaf-7 $ cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.18-371.1.2.el5 (mockbuild@builder10.centos.org) (gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-54)) #1 SMP Tue Oct 22 12:51:53 EDT 2013
```

Comment: Is it giving `xclip: command not found` as an error when you try the command? That means, `xclip` is not installed and you need to install it. Also, please mention what linux OS you are using and also paste the output of the commands you tried in the question.

Comment: And your distro?

Comment: @enedil Clearly CentOS 5.

Comment: Does `xsel -b` work? (It should be equivalent to `xclip -selection clipboard`.) Run `echo wibble | strace -o copy.strace xclip -selection clipboard` and `strace -o paste.strace xclip -selection clipboard -o -` and post the resulting traces.

Comment: xsel is not installed.  The first trace gives no output, the second trace gives (only) "wibble" as output.  My clipboard contents stay the same in both cases.

Comment: What did you try to say it doesn't work? What's the outcome (something else pasted, nothing pasted when you query the clipboard selection)

Comment: After `echo hi | xclip -sel c`, is `xclip` running or is something else stealing the selection? Can you identify the source of the selection? Do you have a clipboard manager running?

Comment: xclip seems to run, it is installed and I can run it in verbose mode (no useful output).  It just doesn't put anything in the clipboard.  I am running over SSH from a mac, but it still works about 40% of the time; I just don't understand why it doesn't work all the time.  Any alternative ways to do this would be fine too....

Answer (score 6):

X doesn't really have a "clipboard" by default. [Selections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_selection) are managed by the application that "owns" them, and if you want to copy or paste a selection, this is done by communication between both applications, which means the other application that holds the selection must still be running.

There is however a method to take over a selection, so there are generic clipboard applications like `xclipboard`, which allow other applications to "send" a `XA_CLIPBOARD` selection.

So, (1) either run `xclip` with option `-l` so it keeps running until a second application pastes successfully (that can require several communication rounds, so `-l 1` can fail), or (2) run a clipboard manager, and use `-selection XA_CLIPBOARD`.

You also said "you're clipboard contents don't change", but it's not really clear which "clipboard" you mean, and how the checked that.